# SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE %?%

Tags: php, mysql

Based on information here [MySQL query String contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602252/mysql-query-string-contains)
trying to create pdo query with `?`

Experimented with following

`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE %?%`

`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE ?%`

`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE %?`

Nothing works. Get error

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '%...

Tried with `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE ?` but this is not for `contains`

Aim is to get query `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column contains ?`

What is is correct pdo `contains` statement for positional placeholders (`?`)?

Comment: manually append and prepend % to value before passing to query as argument. See Example #6 second part http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this by concatenating the value in the string via PHP,

```
$value = "valueHere";
$passThis = "%" . $value . "%";
// other pdo codes...
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE ?");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $passThis);
// other pdo codes...
```

Answer (score 3):

after like add quotes. eg:- `like '%?%'`

i.e:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name like '%field_name%';
```

Comment: `?` is a placeholder for a passed in parameter, it won't work in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I think wildcard stament should be within single quotes, like;

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE '%?%';
```

This returns any record which contains the string given anywhere within the particular column field

Column data which starts with 'ber', example

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE 'ber%';
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `?` is a placeholder for a passed in parameter, it won't work in quotes.

Comment: i expected pdo to be flexible, it seems pdo would tie your hands up for each query. well the price that you pay to be constructive i guess...

Answer (score 1):

Either put the `%` characters before and after your parameter before you pass it into the query or

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE '%' + ? + '%'

SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE ? + '%'

SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE '%' + ?
```

Although this will fail if ? is null because the concatenate will yield null. you could use coalesce

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE '%' + Coalesce(?,'') + '%'

SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE Coalesce(?,'') + '%'

SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE '%' + Coalesce(?,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use prepared statements then take a look at http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepared-statements.php.

```
SELECT * FROM REGISTRY where name LIKE '%?%'
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php Example #6 Invalid use of placeholder