# MySQL query String contains opposite

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[MySQL query String contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602252/mysql-query-string-contains)

Hello, I am trying to make an mysql query that looks for a column value that contains a string from a master string I set. So if my master string is '1234567', I would like it to return any results with column values that have '1','2', etc... The above link was as close as to what I can find but I need it comparing in the opposite direction.

eg.:

```
WHERE '%{$needle}%' LIKE `column`
```

Comment: think you'll need to split it character by character if you want to look for `1`, `2` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
WHERE ? LIKE CONCAT('%', `column`, '%')
```

where `?` is a placeholder having a bound parameter with your *master* value (1234567) because you **are** using the PDO or MySQLi extension, right?

You're most certainly not using the deprecated MySQL extension, surely.

Answer (score 1):

You are a little vague about where the various values are being stored (your text uses terms like "master string" but the sample code uses different names).

You can do what you want using `regexp`.  Here is an example:

```
select 'abcd6efg' regexp concat('.*[', '1234567', '].*')
```

To be honest, `regex` is different from `like` in one important respect.  `regex` returns true if any part of the left string matches, whereas for `like` the entire string has to match.  So, the following also works:

```
select 'abcd6efg' regexp concat('[', '1234567', ']')
```

I like to put the explicit wildcards in to avoid mistakes when switching between the two.

You can look up the documentation for regular expressions [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html).