# MySQL: Select Column names containing a string

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get data from columns containing a particular string in their name in my case it it *PLA*. Though their is a way to select where the values are like as in [MySQL query String contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602252/mysql-query-string-contains). Is there a similar way for the column name?

```
SELECT COLUMN NAMES LIKE '%PLA%' FROM `TABLENAME` WHERE MONTH=? AND YEAR=?
```

Comment: Why do you need that? How would you process results if you don't know column names?

Comment: When you come across questions like this as you are coding, never overlook a chance to ask yourself, "what if what I am trying to do is hard... because my design is flawed?"  Data isn't column names and column names aren't data and you should never have to write a query that blurs the boundary like this in a well-designed database.  It is possible, to assemble such a query, using a query to information_schema.columns, as is explained below.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`SELECT COLUMN NAMES` is not valid in MySQL. There are similar things such as `DESCRIBE [table];` or `SHOW COLUMNS FROM [table];`, but you can't put WHERE clauses on them. Much better is to use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` virtual DB e.g. -

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
 WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='[database name]' and `TABLE_NAME`='[table name]'
 AND   `COLUMN_NAME` LIKE '%PLA%'
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/columns-table.html for more information.

Comment: thanks for the link though I liked the `SHOW COLUMNS FROM tbl_name LIKE 'PLA'`...

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT (SELECT COLUMN NAMES FROM 'TABLENAME') AS CNAME WHERE CNAME LIKE '%PLA%'
```