# SQLite Select data where the column name contains a string?

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to get data from columns containing a particular string in their name. I have found the answer for MySql [MySQL: Select Column names containing a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851343/mysql-select-column-names-containing-a-string) but I need to do the same query for SQLite.
Any suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SQLite 3.16, you can use PRAGMAs in queries:

```
SELECT name
FROM pragma_table_info('MyTable')
WHERE name LIKE ...
```