# SQLite Select data where the column name contains a string and create a table with those headers only

Tags: sql, sqlite, pragma

Following from the answer to this question:
[SQLite Select data where the column name contains a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50043164/sqlite-select-data-where-the-column-name-contains-a-string)

I would like to know how to create a table with these new columns obtained from the previous table.
I wrote something like this (Please ignore the `WHERE` statement):

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
AS(
SELECT name
FROM pragma_table_info("old_table")
WHERE name NOT LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\'
FROM old_table
);
```

however, it is not working.
Any help in this direction would be much appreciated.
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the columns of `old_table` then you can do it like this:

```
create table new_table as
select * from old_table
where 0;
```

If you want specific columns you must specify them on the `select` list:

```
create table new_table as
select col1, col2, ... from old_table
where 0;
```

Comment: thanks @forpas,
if possible, I would avoid to write all the column names of the columns I need, they are quite a few...I was hoping to filter them. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: You must specify explicitly all the column names that you want.

Comment: Ok I see, but what if you have hundreds of columns? Shall I just copy the create table statement and delete the columns not needed? Thanks again @forpas !

Comment: If you have hundreds of columns in a table then you should rethink your design before you create another table with hundreds of columns.