# I want to write a SQL Command to fetch the Column Names from a inf2 table where column name must have a particular year or month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, that have column name as 2/may/2018, 2/june/2018, etc. Now I want to fetch the details from the columns that have may in their name.

Comment: This looks like a really bad table design

Comment: It is. But it's a data from a website not self created

Comment: Oh boy, this is messy. You can figure out if certain column exists in a table or not by querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA, but you won't be able to pull its value this way. I'd suggest use something like PowerQuery to convert data into more usable format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
 WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='[database name]' and `TABLE_NAME`='[table name]'
 AND `COLUMN_NAME` LIKE '%may%'
```

This should work. You can also refer to this answer which is for a similar query. - [MySQL: Select Column names containing a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851343/mysql-select-column-names-containing-a-string)

Comment: Also In case I need it in some range like for 2018 to 2019?

Comment: In there WHERE clause, you can add this: AND (`COLUMN_NAME` LIKE '%2018' OR `COLUMN_NAME` LIKE '%2019')

Comment: @karthik_ghorpade to search between dates.. use the BETWEEN Clause , 
SELECT * FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '1996-07-01' AND '1996-07-31';
Source W3Schools

Comment: @Demeteor I think OP wanted to understand how to find the data from tables with columns containing the years 2018 or 2019 in their names, and not all records between a given date range. Please re-read the original question.

Comment: @ShaliniSharma, do let me know if this solution worked for you

Comment: @karthik_ghorpade you are correct he wants records with May in the name. my bad cheers for pointing it out

Comment: @karthik_ghorpade, demeteor thanks a lot for urs answers.  This worked for me.