# How to determine if specific value is included in a csv formatted field in MySQL using raw SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

`specificId` field in `tbl`, value like:

`52890,56518,53034,53968,34830,30188,31311,31309,347,40340,31409,38334,37718,40654,26662,39016,26022,50740`

These are csv format, how to use raw SQL to figure out, whether this record contains `52890`, so if it contains, sql it out, if not contains, I don't want to sql it out in result.

How to do this?

I can use PHP to make this, but it has a pagination problem, I have to make the page size correct, so must be done when I sql it, FYI, the PHP code I used is below:

```
if(isset($specificId) && is_numeric($specificId)) {
    foreach($list as $k => $item){
        $specificIdArr = explode(',', $item['specificId']);
        if( !in_array($specificId, $specificIdArr) )
            unset($list[$k]);
    }
}
```

I've tried using `find_in_set()`, it works, but a little problem, how to remove the result if this field is `null` by using `find_in_set()`.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that all numbers in your "CSV" field have the same length?

Comment: @PM77-1 No, they are not same length

Comment: There are multiple suggested solutions in [MySQL query String contains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602252/mysql-query-string-contains) post.  Have a look.

Comment: You can always check `IS NOT NULL` first.

Comment: @PM77-1 Thank you, `IS NOT NULL` works.

Comment: I would like to point out that storing multiple values in one column is the incorrect way to use a relational database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET` function to search a specific value in a CSV list.
And use a where clause that checks and omits `NULL` rows.

**Example**:

```
drop table if exists so.tbl_so_q23644829;
create table so.tbl_so_q23644829( csv_column varchar(1024) );
insert into so.tbl_so_q23644829 values( '52890,56518,53034,53968,34830,...' );

select * from so.tbl_so_q23644829 
 where find_in_set( '52890', csv_column ) > 0
   and csv_column is not null;
+-----------------------------------+
| csv_column                        |
+-----------------------------------+
| 52890,56518,53034,53968,34830,... |
+-----------------------------------+
```

**Refer to**:

- [*FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

  - Return the index position of the first argument within the second argument