# How to match comma separated values in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a string of ids like tsid = '1,2,3,4'

Now i want to match this tsid with a column of a mysql database. The values in column ia also comma separated like this '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10'

Now i want a sql query which finds the tsid in a column.

I have tried tsid like '%".$tsIdsAll."%'" But this is not fetching right result.How to do this?

Thanks

Comment: what does it fetch when you put like ... in your query?

Comment: Only very painfully.  That is why you should use a junction table instead of storing ids in a string.

Comment: First, retrieve the comma seperated string. Then explode the string and loop it trough, matching it.

Comment: Peter i was thinking to do this. But keeping it as my last option. Any other idea?

Comment: If you want to do it in mysql, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602252/mysql-query-string-contains

Comment: '%YOUR_SEARCH%' should work if there is a match.

Comment: Pols if we have tsid '1,2' and in db we have '21,22'. this will also match up

Answer (score 0):

1. convert both normal and db strings into an 2 arrays using explode.
2. then perform `array_diff()`.
3. u find the results easily.

Comment: ofcourse Marcus. I wanted to do it in mysql way. otherwise i will do it in this way

Comment: k mate. but i think mysql only has the LIKE (%) keyword. but it doesn't produce the exact result.