# I'm having lots of trouble getting my SQL procedure to work properly

Tags: sql, database

I'm trying to do a practice question for my SQL class and I'm having lots of trouble getting my query to work properly, here's my code - can anyone help me?

> 6. Write a stored procedure called LookUpCustomer that accepts any part of a Customers last name.
>      Return all the customer attributes for those customers from the customer table.

Code:

```
Create Procedure LookUpCustomer 
    (@CustomerLastName varchar(30) = null)
as
    select CustomerLastName 
    from Customer
    where @CustomerLastName like ('_[A-Z]_')
```

I'm getting these results:

```
CustomerLastName:
Simpson,
Jones,
Forman,
smilie,
Lauper,
Marley,
Presely,
Clapton,
Johnson,
Douglas,
Leno,
Little,
Tyler,
McDonald,
Carlson,
```

but I need it so it takes any part of a customer last name, I don't know if this is working properly, thanks to all that help out!

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LookUpCustomer ( @CustomerLastNamePart VARCHAR( 30 ) = NULL ) AS
    SELECT CustomerLastName
    FROM Customer
    WHERE CustomerLastName LIKE '%{@CustomerLastNamePart}%'
```

Further reading...

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html

[MySQL query String contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602252/mysql-query-string-contains)

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try :
select CustomerLastName from Customer WHERE    CustomerLastName LIKE '%' +@CustomerLastName+'%'