# select rows containing a string in a specific column

Tags: php, mysql

Content of entire `pos` column is `home01+home03` or `home02+home04`.
I need to select rows where `pos` contains `home01`.

```
$pos = 'home01';
$stmt = $db->query("select * from banners where pos contains '" . $pos . "'");
```

Nothing is selected.
Also I need to avoid `LIKE` statement because of large table.
Any help?

Comment: `where left(pos,6) = '.$pos."'"`  or you could pass in length of pos as an attribute.

Comment: @xQbert, content is dinamically changed - is not always the same position of a string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602252/mysql-query-string-contains or use regular expression... looking for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use match againts

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD FULLTEXT(pos);

SELECT * FROM banners MATCH(pos) AGAINST('+$pos+');
```

Answer (score 0):

use this query

```
select * from banners where pos like'%" . $pos . "'";
```

this query return all row where first match home01

Comment: Per question, "I need to avoid LIKE statement because of large table."

Comment: `like` is very slow in a large content.

Comment: hey then you have to do indexing of that column

Comment: @amit gaud yes if use indexing then if think will be no problem