# Contains keyword in sql server not giving correct results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have sql query as shown below

```
        SELECT ID,[description1],[description2]
        FROM [instance]
        WHERE CONTAINS([description2],'"*ECSB10*"')
```

It is giving following rows with description2 value 'VA-7000-ECSB02-1B-MGMT' even though description2 column does not contain keyword ECSB10, Can anyone explain why is it returning like this.

[image: result]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL query String contains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602252/mysql-query-string-contains)

Comment: Full-Text Search is *language* based, not *string* based. I wouldn't be surprised if it's stripping the digits from your input since *those aren't part of a word*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ,  if it strips digits, then the result should be same if I use '"*ECSB20*"' as filter, instead it is returning zero rows

Comment: it seems like my full text search index has not been build properly

Answer (score 0):

SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM table_name
WHERE column2 LIKE '%{$...}%'

Answer (score 0):

I think you better use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT ID, [description1],[description2]
FROM [instance]
WHERE [description2] like '%ECSB10%'
```