# Why does this SQL query not returning only one record (utf8 problem)?

Tags: mysql, sql, utf-8, mariadb

If I do a SQL query like this one on my db:

```
 SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE fieldname LIKE "%ác%";
```

these are the rows it returns:

[image: query results]

Clearly I only want the second record. I have added to my.cnf file this lines:

```
[client]

default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

and my database was created like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE database name CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

and it still doesn't work as it should be working.

Comment: Well you're assuming `'á'` is _unlike_ `'a'`. Why?

Comment: Well, in spanish it's very different!

Comment: First of all you should fix your configuration file. Why do you disable setting character set during handshake?

Comment: I read an article talking about the issue with utf8 and MariaDB:
https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#utf8-to-utf8mb4
They suggest to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to all utf8mb4 collations except 'icelandic' and 'bin', `a` = `á`.  That includes utf8mb4_spanish2_ci and utf8mb4_spanish_ci.

utf8mb4_spanish2_ci treats `ch` and `ll` as "separate letters", unlike most collations.  Do you need that?

Both Spanish collations treat `ñ` as distinct from `n`.

More details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html

utf8mb4_0900_as_ci is "accent sensitive" (as you requested) and "case insensitive".  Maybe that is what you need?

Please provide more details so we can help you further.

Comment: Thank you for your support. It seems that "utf8mb4_0900_as_ci" collation isn't supported in MariaDB, only with MySQL. Is it possible?

If so, I haven't found any collation in MariaDB that can do the query properly.

Comment: @JanoSoler - Alas, only MySQL 8.0 has the _as_ci collation.  This is the quick way to find out Collations your version has:  `SHOW COLLATION LIKE 'utf8mb4%';`

Comment: @JanoSoler also utf8mb4_es_0900_as_cs, utf8mb4_es_trad_0900_as_cs, utf8mb4_0900_as_cs are on 8.0.17.

Comment: I didn't know this: `SHOW COLLATION LIKE 'utf8mb4%';` It is clear MariaDB isn't very good suited to support databases with content in spanish. Thank you again @RickJames

Comment: @JanoSoler - Can you spell out all the requirements for Spanish collation?

Comment: Of course:
a<>á
a<>ä
n<>ñ
c<>ç
á<>à
Collation must be case sensitive in my case too.

Comment: @JanoSoler - See if `utf8_bin` meets all your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently á is like a. You can use [`INSTR()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2602280/7032856) instead for an exact string inclusion.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 'caracteres ingleses' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci fieldname
UNION ALL
SELECT 'carácteres no ingles' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    ) A
-- WHERE fieldname LIKE '%ác%'
WHERE INSTR(fieldname, 'ác')
;
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. I don't think that solution works for me, I don't want to do it at query level, I want do it ant db scheme, so all the queries can work without "extra work". Anyway, thank you very much.