# if contains in column ID

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How I can join two tables if one column contains multiple ID's.

Little story, I have branch and in my branch have many employees and managers.
I have table Branch where is column managers and employees.

I have to show to each my manager his branches.

Branch table

| ID | Name | Business_ID | Managers | Employees | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Beauty | 15 | 4,5,9,17 | 44,76,54,72 | 1 |

So if I'm manager and my id is 5 I should see this "Beauty" row.

---

table > branch

| id | name | address | for_who | description | icon | start_time | end_time | business_id | is_featured | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Beauty OY | New York avn 6 | 1 | Little desc.. | 45hjds.png | 09:00:00 | 19:00:00 | 15 | 1 | 1 |

table > branch_categories

| branch_id | category_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

table > branch_managers

| branch_id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 9 |
| 1 | 17 |

table > branch_employees

| branch_id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 44 |
| 1 | 76 |
| 1 | 54 |
| 1 | 72 |

---

Model > Branch.php

```
public $table = 'branch';

protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'deleted_at',
];
protected $guarded = [];

protected $withCount = ['reviews'];
protected $appends = ['imageUri', 'avg_rating'];
public function getImageUriAttribute()
{
    if (isset($this->attributes['icon'])) {

        return url('upload/') . '/' . $this->attributes['icon'];
    }
}
public function managers(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Branch::class);
}

public function employees(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Branch::class);
}

public function getAvgRatingAttribute()
{

    $revData = Review::where('branch_id', $this->attributes['id'])->get();
    $star = $revData->sum('star');
    if ($star > 1) {
        $t = $star / count($revData);
        return number_format($t, 1, '.', '');
    }
    return 0;
}

public function Reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Review', 'branch_id', 'id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

So I created two models more for branch employees and branch manager. But I already have existing EmployeeInfo model and controller. I dont know if doing right way or not.

Model > BranchEmployee.php

```
class BranchEmployee extends Model
{

    use SoftDeletes;

    public $table = 'branch_employees';
    protected $guarded = [];

   
    public function branches(){
      return $this->belongsToMany(BranchEmployee::class);
    }
}
```

and employeeInfo model looks like this:

Model > EmployeeInfo.php

```
class EmployeeInfo extends Model
{

    public $table = 'employee_detail';

    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',

    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'emp_id', 'address', 'description', 'service', 'icon', 'experience', 'status',
    ];

    protected $appends = ['imageUri', 'avg_rating'];
    public function setServiceAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['service'] = implode(',', $value);
    }

    public function getServiceAttribute($value)
    {
        return explode(',', $value);
    }
    public function getImageUriAttribute()
    {
        if (isset($this->attributes['icon'])) {

            return url('upload/') . '/' . $this->attributes['icon'];
        }
    }
    public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'emp_id', 'id');
    }
    public function getAvgRatingAttribute()
    {
        return 4;
        $revData = Review::where('provider_id', $this->attributes['id'])->get();
        $star = $revData->sum('star');

        if ($star > 1) {
            $t = $star / count($revData);

            return number_format($t, 1, '.', '');
        }
        return 'N/A';
    }

}
```

Model > BranchManager.php

```
class BranchManager extends Model
{

    use SoftDeletes;

    public $table = 'branch_managers';
    protected $guarded = [];

   
    public function branches(){
      return $this->belongsToMany(Manager::class);
    }
}
```

---

First I had admin panel created where was easy to query all data from database. Because admin can see all data and limit data with Gate access. But now is harder to create queries for business type of users (Owner, Manager, Employee). I think I've done whole relations with tables wrongly and now im struggling with that.

Business branch controller where I tried to query data only for business owner and manager who owns branches and who have assigned for branches.

Controller > BranchController.php

```
public function index()
{

    if (!Gate::denies('branch_access')) {

        $branch = DB::table('branch')
            ->join('business', 'branch.business_id', '=', 'business.id')
            ->select('branch.id', 'branch.name', 'branch.address', 'branch.for_who', 'branch.start_time', 'branch.end_time', 'branch.icon', 'branch.is_featured', 'branch.status')
            ->where('business.owner_id', Auth::id())
            ->get();
    } elseif (!Gate::denies('branch_manager_access')) {
        $branch = DB::table('branch')
            ->join('business', 'branch.business_id', '=', 'business.id')
            ->join('branch_managers', 'branch.id', '=', 'branch_id')
            ->select('branch.id', 'branch.name', 'branch.address', 'branch.for_who', 'branch.start_time', 'branch.end_time', 'branch.icon', 'branch.is_featured', 'branch.status')
            ->where('branch_managers.user_id', Auth::id())
            ->get();
    } else {

        abort_if(true, Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');
    }

    return view('salon.branch.index', compact('branch'));
}
```

Admin - Controller > BranchController.php

```
public function index()
{

    if (!Gate::denies('branch_access')) {
        $branch = branch::all();
    } else {

        abort_if(true, Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');
    }

    return view('admin.branch.index', compact('branch'));
}
```

---

My SaaS project >
What I'm trying to do is that `admin` can view in his panel all infos etc... and Business panel `Owner` can see all his branches and `Manager` can see all assigned branches only.

I've also thinking start all over and with fresh head with good snippets.. I've checked other people repositories. But every saas is different way and more confusing. Multi-tenant was first idea, but I dont need subdomain system, just panel for admins and Vendors (Businesses) and End User (User who's buyng Vendor services / goods).

Comment: It'd be best if you rethink your database design. Seems like `branch_managers` and `branch_employees` should be separate tables. When you design your database like that, then you can utilize common and efficient tools of joining to perform search queries like these, which are made more difficult when you store multiple information in a single column. This way you have to check if the [string contains what you need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602252/mysql-query-string-contains), and you need to cover several cases (at the beginning, at the end or in the middle).

Comment: This kind of schema design will bring you a lot of disadvantages. It's better to create a lookup table. Check this short answer from a developer that used to do it like you https://stackoverflow.com/a/8585080/4577905

Comment: Im gonna redesign my tables, create branch_managers and branch_employees and then use join statements.

Comment: As others stated, you should rather consider a relational DB design. However, MySQL has a FIND_IN_SET method (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/find_in_set/) that would do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

### OK, you're doing this in a bad way. Each branch may have many employees and each employee may have many branches. So, you should create  third table, which is named, employee_branch maybe. And create a many to many relationship. If you're using laravel.
Other option is, you can change your driver from mysql to postgres, which is supports arrays. But the best choice is just creating a many-to-many relationship. If you wanna know how, leave a comment right here

As I got from your table, you have 2 many-to-many relationships.
First one is, branch and managers, second one is, branch and employees.
That's the idea.
When you prepare a many-to-many relationship, you need a third table, named branch_manager. Because a branch belongs to many managers, and a manager belongs to many branches. In the third table, we have branch_id and manager_id. So these two can be joined to each other simply. And after that, you can simply get a manager's branches this way:

```
$branches = Manager::find($id)->branches;
$managers = Branch::find($branchID)->managers;
```

For branch model, you have to create this function:

```
public function managers(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Branch::class);
}
```

And for manager model:

```
public function branches(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Manager::class);
}
```

I think laravel will automatically generate that third table I told you.
And for employees, you should only perform many-to-many between branch and employee.

Comment: Yes im using laravel 7 and I think im gonna still use same driver mysql because I have alot work done, but database tables. Yes I have to edit relationships. Im little confused how to work with that. Maybe you have some tips for me.

Comment: Edited my post.